# Does main()'s pthread ID default to 0?

Tags: pthreads

I'm double-checking some assumptions made in some code I'm maintaining.

Am I correct in understanding that the pthread ID of a program's main() will always be defined as 0?

So, for example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    printf("Main ID is %X\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());
}
```

will always print 0?

This seems to be how it works on my own system (Linux, GNU_LIBPTHREAD_VERSION is: NPTL 2.11.1), but I haven't managed to find any reference to this definition in various explanations of the pthread library. I'd like to know if this behavior is reliable and portable, or if it's just a local fluke. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pthread_t should be treated as an opaque type; there is a function pthread_equal() that you should use to compare thread pthread_t objects. Casting to unsigned int is definitely undefined behavior, as is comparing to an int with ==.

Answer (score 1):

A fellow named "Unemployed Russian" edited my other answer to include the following; I personally don't buy it, but perhaps there's something to it?

> In addition, the zero you've got was printed only because you actually didn't link with libpthread at all. Consider:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    printf("Main ID is %lx\n", (unsigned long)pthread_self());
}

$ g++ -g t.c  && ./a.out
Main ID is 0
$ g++ -g t.c -pthread && ./a.out
Main ID is 7fd1a288d720
```

I don't buy this because on my MacBook, I get

```
$ g++ -g t.c  && ./a.out
Main ID is a092e720
```

Comment: This is implementation-specific. Surely there are some (IMO broken) implementations where the real `pthread_self` is in `libpthread` and stub pthread functions exist in the main libc, so I'm not at all surprised if this happens. On the other hand it's definitely not something you can rely on.